# Error 6985 and 6988 in applet installation process

Tags: java, javacard

I wrote a very simple program for my java card as follow :

```
package myFirstApplet;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class ECHO extends Applet 
{

    private ECHO() 
        {
        }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException 
        {
        new ECHO().register();
        }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException 
        {
        byte[] received=arg0.getBuffer();
        ++received[(short)(received.length+1)];
        arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)received.length); 
        }

}
```

It is written in a way to receive an APDU command, add it by one and send it to cardholder again.

After converting it to *.cap* file successfully, when I want to install it using *GP tool*, I receive `6985` error:

```
GP: gp -install d:\myFirstApplet.cap
openkms.gp.GPException: LOAD failed SW: 6985
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:924)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:606)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:565)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:330)

GP:
```

And `6985` & `6988` when I try to install it using *JCManager* :

```
Authenticated
************
UplaodCAP
*************
Get AID from header.cap file
FOR LOAD DATA: EF 04 C6 02 01 28
AID:01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00
Applet AID:01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Try to delete if existing...
-> 84 E4 00 00 18 90 5E F7 BC 5C 13 70 27 E5 F1 26 4F AC 70 96 B8 FE F5 89 CC 93 D7 2E 24
<- 6A 88
-> 84 E4 00 00 18 3D 62 7D 1A 35 76 4F 38 12 DE BB 69 9F 21 70 7F 29 23 08 D0 36 85 FF E5
<- 6A 88
Loading cap file. Please wait...
Install for Load
-> 84 E6 02 00 18 4F 24 95 04 0B 3A DE 26 24 1D D5 ED 5B 9A 0F D0 36 52 1E A1 AC 0B BB 76
<- 00 90 00
Load CAP
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
<- 69 85
-> 84 E6 0C 00 38 4F 24 95 04 0B 3A DE 26 82 5E CB 04 65 42 EB 3E 4F 8A 6D 37 18 E0 79 79 44 1F 58 55 DB 4E 50 BC 8F 4D 73 2A BC 60 80 42 60 A9 9B 3E 81 0A 95 85 DA 65 2B AA 91 82 CF 7A
<- 6A 88
Could not load applet. See debug for more info
```

Am I wrong in something?

And also I am a little confused about the `process` method of my program.

In the first line I copy the contents of APDU buffer to my array that named `Received`:

```
    byte[] received=arg0.getBuffer();
```

In the second line, I added by one the last member of this array :

```
    ++received[(short)(received.length+1)];
```

Now I send the APDU buffer to the user :

```
    arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)received.length);
```

Right? If so, I didn't change the receiving APDU command! I just received it, made a copy of it, changed the copy, and send the original buffer again! right?

Comment: Down voter, please explain why?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time (didn't downvote). Note that your APDU handling is non-existent, and your code is wrong as well (`received.length + 1` will obviously not fit in the APDU buffer, and you need to receive data before being able to change it)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes OK, Thank you. **Note that your APDU handling is non-existent** , may I ask you to explain it? what do you mean by "non-existent"?(if possible make it an answer and let  me check it.)

Comment: **you need to receive data before being able to change it**. Didn't I? So what is this line for? `byte[] received=arg0.getBuffer();`

Comment: **received.length + 1 will obviously not fit in the APDU buffer**, Yes. you are right. I remove the **+1**, and now it is installed successfully. But JCRE returns `6F00` in respond to `SELECT` APDU command.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Moreover, Shouldn't the compiler or converter check the program for mistakes like this(`received.length + 1`) before creating _.cap_ files?

Comment: 1) call `setIncomingAndReceive` if you expect data in your command. 2) `received.length` is still an indexoutofbounds, I do not know why +1 is caught at install time and the other one isn't. 3) the compiler and converter aren't full fletched static code analyzers, you will still be able to generate runtime exceptions (this is even true if they did contain static code analysis, but this error may have been caught).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ,Oops! You are right again! :D . `received.length-1`  is the last member if this array, right?

Comment: It's the last member of the buffer, but the array is not sized according tot the incoming data, it's probably a statically sized array (initialized to zero between calls to `process()`). To retrieve the incoming length (Nc, currently still called Lc in the JavaDoc) call `setIncomingAndReceive()`.

Answer (score 0):

The README of the loading software has pretty straightforward guide for getting support:

https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#contact

Also, your package name suggests you are not using the latest version. Please use the latest version before sending any logs.

I suspect the applet is not suitable for your card because you are using features (packages) your card does not have. In this case I suspect your cap targets a newer javacard version.

Comment: 1- I downloaded the **gp.exe** 10 hour ago!! 2-My smart card is a JavaCard 3.0.1 !